# Add form field data based on user input

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a Quiz with a number of questions the user inputs in a form (also with a tag, but that's not the point here). I've tried the following but I do not feel this is the right approach. I am thinking there must be another way instead of manually calling Quiz.objects.create() with data I got from the form. Also even if the Quiz object gets created, I'm getting the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_of_questions = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    time_limit = models.IntegerField(default=300)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

**forms.py**

```
class QuizForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        exclude = ['questions']

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        questions = get_questions_with_tag('example_tag')
        questions = questions[:data['number_of_questions']]
        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(name=data['name'],
                               time_limit=data['time_limit'],
                               number_of_questions=data['number_of_questions'])
        for q in questions:
            quiz.questions.add(q)

        quiz.save()
```

**views.py**

```
class AddQuizView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'quiz/cpanel/add_quiz.html'
    form_class = QuizForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list_quizzes')
```

Can you suggest a better approach that will involve only adding the questions list to the form request?

Comment: Where are the questions coming from? What is `get_questions_with_tag`?

Comment: It's a list of objects of type Question. I'm just querying the database there: `Question.objects.filter(tag__name=tag)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more tries, I came up with this:

```
def save(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data

    questions = get_questions_with_tag('example_tag')
    questions = questions[:data['number_of_questions']]

    self.instance.save()
    self.instance.questions = questions

    quiz.save()
```

It fixes the error I had and also I'm no longer manually creating an object of type Quiz.